# How to see fixed columns on print view, using dataTables with FixedColumns and TableTools

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

I'm using DataTables with FixedColumns and TableTools extras among others.

When I click Print button for seeing the print preview, the fixed columns are not shown, but PDF and Excel functions prints all the columns.

Here you can see a live example:
http://live.datatables.net/epuxem/9
(Print button is the one labeled as "Imprimir" in the live example)

How can I make to see the whole table in the print view?

Comment: i also facing same issue..do u find any solution..if any solution,pls share...

Comment: no solution or answer to it. Temporary I built my own personaliced method to show the "print view" but wasn't completely satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a separate style sheet in your header that is used specifically for the print view.  In this style sheet you can add styles to your data tables to show the fixed lines for your columns, as well as, any other print view related styles you are looking to include.

Add to your header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="/projName/css/print.css" media="print">
```

print.css example to add lines to your data table:

```
#tableId .tdClassNameForLeftBorder {
   border-left: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}
```